# How can I generate a random time in PHP shorter than a given time?

Tags: php, time

I have a given time duration such as `00:10:15`. I want to generate a random time shorter than this, eg: `00:09:18` or `00:02:15`. How to do this with PHP?

Comment: Express that time as a number of seconds (simple number), then use a simple call to `mt_rand($min, $max)`…

Comment: that given time minus a random number of seconds

Answer (score -4, accepted):

it`s easy to deal it with `explode` and `mt_rand`, like :
    
    `list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', '00:10:15');
    $newHour = str_pad(mt_rand(0, $hour), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $newMinute = str_pad(mt_rand(0, $minute), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $newSecond = $newMinute == $minute ? mt_rand(0, $second) : mt_rand(0, 59);
    $newSecond = str_pad($newSecond, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $newTime = "{$newHour}:{$newMinute}:{$newSecond}";`

Comment: This misses out chunks of time below the subject time, e.g. if subject is `00:10:15` then there will never be seconds greater than 15 generated by the above code, even though e.g. `00:09:59` is below the subject time.

Comment: hi,Divesh choudhary, use this edited one plz, a little bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks Can you modify it accordingly  if time is 00:02:00 than output will never 00:02:00 .want  always less than entered time

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to seconds, then you add a random value, then you convert back to time format.

```
$time = '00:10:15';
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(":", $time);
$seconds = $s + ($m * 60) + ($h * 3600);

$seconds -= rand(0, $seconds); //set desired min and max values

// now back to time format
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins = floor($seconds / 60 % 60);
$secs = floor($seconds % 60);

$timeFormat = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

[Run test code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad1858fabc177e08f83aaf7d945efb07cfe8d154)

Comment: The question is for a time *less than* the supplied value, not *up to 24 hours greater*.

Comment: sometime genrate more than 00:10:15.need to take it less then give time

Comment: Mine was just an example and I used `+` instead of `-`. Not a good reason for downvoting. The OP should put his own values in it

Comment: Providing an answer that doesn't answer the question is reason for downvoting.  Thanks for editing, and improving, your answer.

Comment: I just missed on "less than" in OP post :) Sorry

Comment: Why not to use `$seconds = rand(0, $seconds)` instead of `$seconds -= rand(0, $seconds)`?

Answer (score 0):

(still adding my solution, as i don't like any of the existing answers)

use strtotime() to parse your "00:10:15" to an unix timestamp, use rand() to get the some random time within that timestamp, and date() to convert the unix timestamp back to your "00:10:15" format.

```
<?php
$minimum_time=strtotime("00:00:00");
$maximum_time=strtotime("00:10:15");
$rand=rand($minimum_time,$maximum_time);
$str=date("H:i:s",$rand);
echo $str;
```

- if you need  cryptographically secure randomness, use random_int() instead of rand(). (PHP7+)